# How to pass through {{ double bracket in mustache

Tags: mustache, icanhaz.js

Quick question.
I have a template that is rendered in mustache in php.
But it includes sections that are to be rendered in ICH in the client browser.

I cannot work out how to tell mustache in php not to render {{var}} that I want to pass to ICH.

IE I want to see {{variable}} in the html source so that ICH can pick it up.

How do I escape {{ to get it past the php mustache?

Sample:

```
<script id="user" type="text/html">
    \{\{name\}\} {{twitter}} {{{twitter}}} 
</script>
```

but in my html it becomes

```
<script id="user" type="text/html">
  \{\{name\}\} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the double braces with a backslash like this

```
\{{ name }}
```

Another way is to change the delimeter temporarly like this

```
{{=<% %>=}}
 {{name}}
<%={{ }}=%>
```

Sorry, I can't comment your post because of my reputation.

Comment: The first answer doesn't seem to work but the second one does.
Thanks!

Comment: Escaping the double braces is a handlebars thing, not mustache. Changing delimiters is the way to go :)